# Proper way to add field to the user collection in meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

So I'm trying to add an 'account_type' field to the user collection.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (Meteor.users.find().count() === 0){
        var user = Accounts.createUser({
            email: 'email@fake.com',
            password: 'password'
        });
        Meteor.users.update({_id: user}, {$set : {account_type: 'admin'}});
    }
});
```

When I call `Meteor.user().account_type`, it's undefined.

I also read somewhere that something like this may be necessary:

```
Meteor.methods({
    get_user: function(user_id){
        return Meteor.users().find({ _id: user_id}, {fields: {account_type: 1}});
    }
});
```

But I get undefined again when I call it:

```
console.log(Meteor.call('get_user', Meteor.userId()));
```

What is the proper way to add to the user model?

Comment: Tip: instead of `find({_id: uid})` it's enough to write the shorthand form `find(uid)`, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have account type visible on the client, you need to create publish / subscribe channel with needed field. Meteor only publishes `username`, `email` and `profile` by default. Calling a method to get a field from db is a bad idea in 99% of cases.

To start with, server code:

```
Meteor.publish('users', function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {accountType: 1}});
});
```

Client:

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('users');
});
```

When you get this running, next make sure that client doesn't get sensitive information about other users.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working still.  I tried logging `Meteor.users.update({_id: user}, {$set : {account_type: 'admin'}});` and it says undefined.  Could there be a reason this is failing?

Answer (score -1):

You should use the callback of the function to get the result:

```
Meteor.call('get_user', Meteor.userId(), function(error, result){
    // do something with result
    console.log(error, result);
});
```

For the other bit, try with:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (Meteor.users.find().count() === 0){
        var user = Accounts.createUser({
            email: 'email@fake.com',
            password: 'password'
        });
        Meteor.users.update({_id: user._id}, {$set : {account_type: 'admin'}});
    }
});
```

Notice that I added `user._id`.

Comment: This is wrong: `Accounts.createUser` returns `_id` of created user, not the whole object.