# Meteor: How should I update the Users collection to include a new attribute in the object / dictionary?

Tags: mongodb, collections, meteor, publish-subscribe, meteor-accounts

I've tried looking for an answer all over but cannot seem to get this working. I'm using Meteor with Cordova to build a mobile app.

I want to add an attribute to my Users collection (the one Meteor creates when I'm logged in). ie. For example, I want to add {currentHotel: "Something"} to my db.Users collection.

I'm trying to do this the correct, Publish - Subscribe way. Using Meteor.methods has been quoted to not be good for real - time applications. Either way, I want to understand how to update the Users collection using Publish - Subscribe.

```
//On the server, I did
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
       {fields:{services: 1, currentHotel: 1}});
});
```

So the currentHotel field should be accessible to the client side. Now to update the "currentHotel" field:

```
//On the client I do
Meteor.subscribe('userData');
var user = Meteor.users.findOne({"_id": Meteor.userId()});
Meteor.users.update({_id: user._id}, {$set:{currentHotel:'something'}});

//I tried this too
//Meteor.users.update({ _id: Meteor.userId() }, {$set: });
```

On the browser console I can see "currentHotel" and "services" just fine, which means the publish-subscribe worked. Yet I cannot seem to update the currentHotel. I get an Access Denied. Why is this?

Additionally, If the "currentHotel" property did not exist in the Collection at all, how can I add it using a similar publish-subscribe? Can I publish a property that isn't there and allow the client to subscribe and add that property?

I referred to the Meteor docs, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198683/subscribing-to-meteor-users-collection), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367644/proper-way-to-add-field-to-the-user-collection-in-meteor) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630829/meteor-pass-data-from-client-to-server), but still cannot seem to get it to work! :-(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not supposed to change the root fields of the user object:

```
Meteor.users.update(user, {$set: {"profile.currentHotel": "something"}});
```

Read more here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users

EDIT: This answer has become irrelevant as shown in the latest documentation: https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#dont-use-profile

This answer is more than 1 year old :) As it turns out, forcing to write user-specific fields under a 'profile' field as some serious security implications (like I always thought) since it gives permission to the clients to modify those sub-fields. So yes, you can set fields in the root object, but be aware that fields that should not be modified by the client, should be under a field without write permissions (or else it falls under the same problem).

Comment: You're the best! Thank you! I assume I do not need to publish anything to add to this profile object? Edit: Ah, profile is published automatically! Thanks a tonne!

Comment: Thanks, this was useful to me too. Just one note, I got an error by trying to update this way and I had to indicate the _id with `{ _id: Meteor.userId() }` as suggested [in this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23705715/3961519).

Comment: @JoséRicardoRibeiro The doc page you link to doesn't currently mention anything about not adding root fields to the user object (that I can find).  https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#top-level-fields says the best way is to do this.  Which is correct?

Comment: @mpdonadio This answer is more than 1 year old :) And yes, as it turns out, forcing to write user-specific fields under a 'profile' field as some serious security implications (like I always thought) since it gives permission to the clients to modify those sub-fields.

https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#dont-use-profile

So yes, you can set fields in the root object, but be aware that fields that should not be modified by the client should be under a field without write permissions.